# The logic of a module versus the logic of parentheses

Tags: absolute-value

As far as I know, I can easily transform $ - (21x -7) $ into $ 7 - 21x $

But can I do the same with a module?

Would $ - |21x -7| $ also easily transform into  $ 7 - 21x $?
Or only transforming into $ -|7 - 21x| $ would be correct?

Comment: The answer to your first question is No,  since $-|21x-7|\le 0$, whereas $7-21x\le 0$ if & only if $x\ge \dfrac13$.

Comment: The second transformation is correct, since $|Q|=|-Q|$ for all $Q$.